# How to recognize a barcode format

Tags: php, laravel, barcode, barcode-scanner

I'm using Laravel and https://github.com/milon/barcode to generate barcodes.
From an API I got string but not the format.

How to recognize which format is because if I put the wrong format, my function which generates PDF fail.
Is there any PHP to recognize barcode format based on a string?

Comment: How your string look like?

Comment: If only common characters are specified/notified for multiple barcode types, there is no way to distinguish the barcode types. You can tell if a character or data sequence that is only available for some barcode type is used, but the probability is low. As a countermeasure, specify the barcode type from the outside by user instruction etc., or limit the barcode type that can be used.

Comment: ok, just how barcode scanners works... they recognize barcode format